# How to avoid self-joins that result in symmetric results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, self-join

I was looking for records that are within 2 weeks of each other, in the same table, as such:

```
    SELECT stuff  
    FROM mytable AS a
    JOIN mytable AS b 
    ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE      
(
    a.Date = b.Date
    OR
    a.Date  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(b.Date, INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(b.Date, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    OR
    b.Date  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(a.Date, INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(a.Date, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
)
    ;
```

It worked fine, but now I have a result with this type of structure:

```
| ID | a.Date     | b.Date     | a.Value | b.Value |
|----|------------|------------|---------|---------|
| 1  | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 | foo     | bar     |
| 1  | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-01 | bar     | foo     |
```

Either I did my join in a bad way which is leading to this duplicated structure, or the join is okay but I need some way to remove the chiral record.  Can anyone advise me on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
a.Value < b.Value
```

to the `WHERE` clause.

Or, better yet, if you have a primary key (and *all* tables should have a primary key):

```
a.pk < b.pk
```